What is wrong with C++ my code? It return with 3221225477
When I insert slang words, it doesn't save it to the dictionary because when I type 4 it doesn't show anything. It just says no words in the dictionary, I've been trying to debug it all night, but all I get is catching the cold. It might also be a problem with the memory or with my Trie
#include <bits/stdc++.h> // Include the C++ library for common data structures and functions

using namespace std; // Use the standard namespace so we don't have to repeatedly write std everytime

// Node structure for linked list
struct Node { 
    string data; // Declare the data string
    Node* next; // Next pointer
    
    Node(string value){ // Constructor to create a new Node with the given value
        data = value; // Set data as the given value
        next = NULL; // Set next pointer as null
    }
};

// Linked list structure
struct LinkedList {
    Node* head; // Create the node head of the LinkedList

public:

    LinkedList(){ // Constructor to create an empty LinkedList
        head = NULL; // Set pointer to head as null
    }

    ~LinkedList() { // Destructor to free the memory that was occupied by LinkedList
        Node* current = head; // Declare that current node is head of LinkedList
        while (current != NULL) { // While loop as long as current is not NULL
            Node* temp = current; // Set temporary node as current node
            current = current->next; // Set the current node as the next node of current node
            delete temp; // Delete the temporary node
        }
    }

    void append(string value) { // Function to append to the LinkedList
        Node* newNode = new Node(value); // Create a new node with the given value
        if (head == NULL) { // If head is null
            head = newNode; // Set the new node as the head
        } else {
            Node* current = head; // Set current node as the head
            while (current->next != NULL) { // While loop condition as long as the node next to current is not null
                current = current->next; // We set current to the next node of current
            }
            current->next = newNode; // If it's null, then we set the new node as the next node of the current node
        }
    }

    bool contains(string value) { // Function to check if the linked list contains a specific value
        Node* current = head; // Set current node as the head
        while (current != nullptr) { // Loop until current is null
            if (current->data == value) { // If the current node's data matches the given value
                return true; // Return true
            }
            current = current->next; // Move to the next node
        }
        return false; // If no match found, return false
    }

    void print() { // Function to print the words in the linked list
        Node* current = head; // Set the current node as head
        int count = 1; // Start count from 1
        while (current != NULL) { // as long as current is not NULL
            cout << count++ << ". " << current->data << endl; // Print the count, then the current data, then a new line
            current = current->next; // Set current as the next node of current node
        }
    }

    Node* getHead() { // Get the head of the LinkedList
        return head; // return the head
    }
};

// Trie Node structure
struct TrieNode {
    TrieNode* children[26]; // Children pointer, representing the alphabet from 'a' to 'z'
    string description; // String to store the description of the word represented by the trienode
    bool isEndOfWord; // Variable to indicate the end of the word
    LinkedList* prefixList; // pointer to a linked list data structure, store the words that share the same prefix represented by the current trienode

    TrieNode() { // Constructor to create an empty trienode
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { // For loop as long as the alphabet
            children[i] = NULL; // Set all children as NULL
        }
        isEndOfWord = false; // Set the end of the word as false since we just started
        prefixList = new LinkedList(); // Set prefixList as a new linked list
    }

    ~TrieNode() { // Destructor for the Trienode
        delete prefixList; // Delete the prefix list
    }
};

// Trie structure
struct Trie {
    TrieNode* root; // Declare the root of the trienode

public:
    Trie() { // Constructor to create an empty trie
        root = new TrieNode(); // declare root as a new trienode
    }

    ~Trie() { // Deconstructor for the trie
        delete root; // Delete the root of the trie
    }

    void insert(string word, string desc) { // Function to insert a new word and description
        TrieNode* node = root; // Set the trienode node as root
        for (char c : word) { // Iterate over each character in the word
            int index = c - 'a'; // Set index as current character - 'a'(64)
            if (!node->children[index]) { // Condition if children at the index is null
                node->children[index] = new TrieNode(); // Then create a new TrieNode at that children
            }
            node->prefixList->append(word); // Appends the word to the list of prefixes with the current node
            node = node->children[index]; // Moves to the child node at the given index
        }
        node->isEndOfWord = true; // Mark the current node as the end of the word
        node->description = desc; // Store the description at the current node
    }

    bool search(string word) { // Function to search for a word
        TrieNode* node = searchNode(word); // Get the node representing the word
        return node != nullptr && node->isEndOfWord; // Return true if the node exists and is marked as the end of a word
    }

    string getDescription(string word) { // Function to get the description of a word
        TrieNode* node = searchNode(word); // Get the node representing the word
        if (node != nullptr && node->isEndOfWord) { // If the node exists and is marked as the end of a word
            return node->description; // Return the description
        }
        return ""; // Otherwise, return an empty string
    }

    LinkedList startsWith(string prefix) { // Function to get all words starting with a given prefix
        LinkedList results; // Declare a new linked list to store the results
        TrieNode* node = searchNode(prefix); // Get the node representing the prefix
        if (node != nullptr) { // If the node exists
            Node* current = node->prefixList->head; // Get the head of the prefix list
            while (current != NULL) { // Loop through the prefix list
                results.append(current->data); // Append each word to the results list
                current = current->next; // Move to the next node
            }
        }
        return results; // Return the results list
    }

    LinkedList getAllWords() { // Function to get all the words in the Trie
        LinkedList results; // Declare a new linked list to store the results
        collectWords(root, "", results); // Call the helper function to collect all words
        return results; // Return the results list
    }

    TrieNode* searchNode(string word) { // Helper function to search for a node representing a word
        TrieNode* node = root; // Start at the root node
        for (char c : word) { // Iterate over each character in the word
            int index = c - 'a'; // Calculate the index based on the character
            if (!node->children[index]) { // If the child node at the index doesn't exist
                return nullptr; // Return null
            }
            node = node->children[index]; // Move to the child node
        }
        return node; // Return the node representing the word
    }

//    void collectWords(TrieNode* node, string word, LinkedList& results) { // Helper function to collect all words in the Trie
//        if (node->isEndOfWord) { // If the current node marks the end of a word
//            results.append(word); // Append the word to the results list
//        }
//        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) { // Iterate over all possible characters
//            if (node->children[i]) { // If the child node exists
//                collectWords(node->children[i], word + char(i + 'a'), results); // Recursively collect words with the current prefix
//            }
//        }
//    }
    void collectWords(TrieNode* node, string prefix, LinkedList& results) {
        if (node->isEndOfWord) {
            results.append(prefix);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (node->children[i]) {
                collectWords(node->children[i], prefix + char(i + 'a'), results);
            }
        }
    }
};

bool isValidWord(string word) { // Function to check if the word has more than one character
    
    // Check if the word has more than one character
    if (word.length() <= 1) {
        return false; // If the word has 0 or 1 character, it's not valid
    }

    // Check if the word contains any spaces
    if (word.find(' ') != string::npos) {
        return false; // If the word contains spaces, it's not valid
    }

    // If the word passes both checks, it is considered valid
    return true;
}

bool isValidDescription(string desc) { // Function to check if the description is valid
    int spaceCount = 0; // Initialize a variable to count spaces
    for (char c : desc) { // Current char iterates over the description
        if (c == ' ') { // if current char is space
            spaceCount++; // Space count is incremented
        }
    }
    return spaceCount > 1; // return true if space count is greater than 1 (description has to be greater than 2 words)
}

int main() {
    Trie dictionary; // Declare Trie as dictionary
    int choice; // Create int choice for menu

    do { // Do-while loop
        cout << "Boogle Slang Word App" << endl; // Print the app name
        cout << "1. Release a new slang word" << endl; // Print menu option 1
        cout << "2. Search a slang word" << endl; // Print menu option 2
        cout << "3. View all slang words starting with a certain prefix word" << endl; // Print menu option 3
        cout << "4. View all slang words" << endl; // Print menu option 4
        cout << "5. Exit" << endl; // Print menu option 5
        cout << "Enter your choice: "; // Prompt user to enter choice
        cin >> choice; // Read user's choice

        switch (choice) { // Switch statement based on user's choice
            case 1: { // Case 1: Release a new slang word
                string word, desc; // Declare strings to store word and description
                do {
                    cout << "Input a new slang word [Must be more than 1 characters and contains no space]: "; // Prompt for word
                    cin >> word; // Read word from user
                    cout << "Input a new slang word description [Must be more than 2 words]: "; // Prompt for description
                    cin.ignore(); // Ignore the newline character left in the input buffer
                    getline(cin, desc); // Read description from user
                } while (!isValidWord(word) || !isValidDescription(desc)); // Loop until a valid word and description are entered

                if (dictionary.search(word)) { // If the word already exists in the dictionary
                    dictionary.insert(word, desc); // Update the description for the existing word
                    cout << "Successfully updated a slang word." << endl; // Print success message
                } else {
                    dictionary.insert(word, desc); // Insert the new word and description
                    cout << "Successfully released new slang word." << endl; // Print success message
                }
                cout << "Press enter to continue..." << endl; // Prompt user to press Enter
                cin.get(); // Wait for user input (consume the newline character)
                break; // Break out of the switch statement
            }
            case 2: { // Case 2: Search a slang word
                string word;
                do {
                    cout << "Input a slang word to be searched [Must be more than 1 characters and contains no space]: ";
                    cin >> word;
                } while (!isValidWord(word));

                if (dictionary.search(word)) { // If the word is found in the dictionary
                    cout << "Slang word : " << word << endl; // Print the word
                    cout << "Description : " << dictionary.getDescription(word) << endl; // Print the description
                } else {
                    cout << "There is no word \"" << word << "\" in the dictionary." << endl; // Print message if word not found
                }
                cout << "Press enter to continue..." << endl;  // User has to press enter to continue
                cin.get();                                       
                break;
            }
            case 3: { // Case 3: View all slang words starting with a certain prefix
                string prefix;
                cout << "Input a prefix to be searched: "; // Prompt for prefix
                cin >> prefix; // Read prefix from user

                LinkedList words = dictionary.startsWith(prefix); // Get the list of words starting with the prefix
                if (words.head == nullptr) { // If the list is empty
                    cout << "There is no prefix \"" << prefix << "\" in the dictionary." << endl; // Print message
                } else {
                    cout << "Words starts with \"" << prefix << "\":" << endl; // Print header
                    words.print(); // Print the list of words
                }
                cout << "Press enter to continue..." << endl;
                cin.get();
                break;
            }
            case 4: { // Case 4: View all slang words
                LinkedList words = dictionary.getAllWords(); // Get the list of all words
                if (words.head == nullptr) { // If the list is empty
                    cout << "There is no slang word yet in the dictionary." << endl; // Print message
                } else {
                    cout << "List of all slang words in the dictionary:" << endl; // Print header
                    words.print(); // Print the list of words
                }
                cout << "Press enter to continue..." << endl;
                cin.get();
                break;
            }
            case 5: { // Case 5: Exit
                cout << "Thank you... Have a nice day :)" << endl; // Print farewell message
                break; // Break out of the switch statement
            }
            default: { // Default case: Invalid choice
                cout << "Invalid choice. Please try again." << endl; // Print error message
                break;                                                                    
            }
        }
    } while(choice != 5); // End loop if choice is equal to 5 (Exit)
    return 0; // Return 0 to indicate successful program execution
}

I tried to use cin.clear() and cin.get(), but it doesn't work. The return value is 3221225477

#include <bits/stdc++.h> // Include the C++ library for common data structures and functions -- No.  Use the proper, standard header files, not this one.

Don't write large chunks of code without testing. Start with an empty main function. Build with extra warnings enabled, and treated as errors. When it builds cleanly, test it. Then after it passes all tests, add a *very small' bit of code, perhaps even just one or two lines. Continue with building and testing as before. That way, when there is a problem, it will become very easy to isolate it, create a [mre], and debug it.

A couple of other notes, what is your actual assignment? Is it to learn about pointers or linked lists or tries? If not, then don't make your own containers. Use std::vector as the default container, or std::map (or std::unordered_map) for a dictionary-type container. And if you're assignment is to learn about pointer, NULL is an old macros for C backward compatibility, use nullptr for null pointer.

int main() { Trie t; Trie t2 = t; } -- double-free error.  Also, what does your code have to do with c++-cli?  Do not use tags that are not relevant to your question.

One big problem that's immediately visible is that you're implementing a linked list... the STL comes with containers that you can use, which eliminates a lot of error potential right away.

And regarding the return value of 3221225477, if you did a quick search you would find out that it's the same as 0xC0000005. And that is the Windows-specific return code for access violation, which means you use an invalid pointer. All very easily found using your favorite search engine. And there are hundreds, if not thousands of duplicates here on Stack Overflow alone.

I can understand trying to implement a trie from scratch, since C++ has no standard trie data structure.  What I don't understand is why you are writing your own linked list class when std::list exists.  Implement your trie class using containers that have already been written and tested.  You don't build a table by building your own hammer, screwdriver and forging your own nults and bolts.

LinkedList startsWith(string prefix) -- There is no need to look further.  Your LinkedList class is being returned by value, and any type that is being returned by value must have the correct copy semantics.  Your LinkedList class does not have the correct copy semantics due to it not respecting the rule of 3.  Go to the Managing resources section of that link, and you will see a similar class that has all of the issues your LinkedList (and Trie class) has right now.

What is wrong is that you fail to use std::list.  It really looks like you have been using Leetcode (or some other competitive coding site) or another low quality source to teach yourself C++. Have a look at learncpp.com, then lookup std::list on cppreference.com. cppreference should be your go-to site from now on. And to really know how to use C++ as it is intended to be used read the C++ core guidelines. If appropiate ask your teacher to do the same.

for (char c : word) { int index = c - 'a' -- What happens if c is a capital letter?  Does that calculation give you the results you want (assuming it's ASCII)?  You will wind up with a negative number for index.  What you really should do is forget about fancy menus or input routines -- you should test your Trie out with known hard-coded data so that you know it actually works correctly.  Once you establish that it works, then you introduce fancy input routines and menus.

#include <bits/stdc++.h> Why are you using a particular compiler's private header file?  Who taught you this?  A friend?  You'll have to unfriend them.  A book?  Burn the book.  A website?  Block the website.

I ran your code, entered a couple of slang words, then displayed them. Everything seemed to run correctly. You should state exactly what you enter to get the program to crash.

That comment // Use the standard namespace so we don't have to repeatedly write std everytime is incomplete; it should end with and so we'll get mysterious error messages because we dumped all the standard library names into the global namespace.

FYI, you can reduce the resolution time for your issues by first searching the internet (which includes StackOverflow) and by stepping through your code with a debugger.  If you can, use existing std data structures and algorithms (they have already been coded and debugged).
